# Java 8 Optional detect empty collection

Tags: java, option-type

Using Java Optional:

```
List<String> myList = ....

Optional.ofNullable(myList)
   .ifPresentOrElse(.. do something.., ()-> log.error("missing list"));
```

I do want to catch in logs when the list is null or empty. The above works perfectly for `null`. How can it be extended to catch the empty collections?

Comment: Where are you using the `stream` in this example?

Comment: so you seriously think those streams are more readable than `myList == null || myList.isEmpty()`?

Answer (score 4):

if you really want to complicate things using `Optional` -

```
Optional.ofNullable(myList).filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
   .ifPresentOrElse(.. do something.., ()-> log.error("missing list"));
```

better would be using the `if-else` -

```
if(myList !=null && !myList.isEmpty()) {
      // do something
} else {
    log.error("missing list");
}
```

further improvement - ensure that the `List` is not assigned a `null` value.

Comment: if the myList is null 'filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())' will through null point exception

Comment: @janith1024 no it wouldn't, `ofNullable` would result in an `empty` Optional for such cases.

Comment: yes that true I have check the implementation of ofNullable. thanks for educate me

Comment: @janith1024 that’s the very purpose of `Optional`. It would render Optional completely useless if you still needed to perform null-checks in the chained operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think going with `if()else{}` is more readable. You can do like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(myList == null || myList.isEmpty() ? null: myList)
       .ifPresentOrElse(.. do something.., ()-> log.error("missing list"));
```

Comment: I thought [`filter` was a poor solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61473197/1746118), its still better than this! :P

Comment: @Naman _filter_ does not cover OP requirement. OP wants to if _mylist_ is empty log something.

Comment: thanks for the edit, and it does..if myList is empty it would result in an empty `Optional` and log something in the `ifPresentorElse` part.